# Can't Load a php file result into a div

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i have been searching for some hours on how to load the result of a php file into a div in my html page, this code worked perfectly on html and even some php files :

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#div").html('<object data="htmlfile.html" style="width:100%; height:100%;">');
});
```

but when i tried to link some php files it wouldn't work, i know that php needs to run on a webserver or something, which i can make then run on wampserver localhost but i have no idea how to call that into my html page, i have also tried to use ajax but i can't get it to work.

EDIT : the problem here was that the project path should be in my webserver, as i'm using wamp for example there is a www path,i copied the project there then the `$("#div").load('/script.php')`; worked perfectly :)

Comment: With `.load()` function

Comment: Would you please check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution to get contents of a file after it's execution on server is a [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Example

php-file **script.php**

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello, world!';
?>
```

js-handler:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#div").load('/script.php');
});
```

So, after clicking `#button` contents of a `#div` will be `"Hello, world!"`.

Path provided to `load` **must be** path form site root (`DOCUMENT_ROOT`). For example

- `/script.php` - path from site root
- `/blog/index.php` - `index.php` file in a `blog` folder of a site

Comment: jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/CP12/Documents/MyBlog/EX1.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
send @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4

Comment: What path did you put in `load()`?

Comment: $("#conts").load("EX1.php");   my index.html is in the same path

Comment: Do you have a web server? Why you load your html as `file//`? It should be loaded as `localhost/index.html` or similar to that.

Comment: i think i have to upload the php file into wamp, then use a http link instead but im not sure how to do that

Comment: its because i'm really new to this, this would be my first website so i'm not really sure how it should be loaded as localhost/index.html

Comment: Please either ask another question or search web, there're thousands of manuals how to start xampp or whatever you have as a webserver.

Comment: thanx for your help i managed to make it work i changed the path :)

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by using `PHP`.

here is the simple code to understand the flow and how to archive that.

Once please go with it..

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "home_db");
?>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"id="tblData" >
    <tr>
        <th style="width:10px;">Select</th>
        <th style="width:20px;"><a href="#" class="pink">ID</a></th>
        <th style="width:50px;"><a href="#" class="pink">Title</a></th>
        <th style="width:auto;"><a href="#" class="pink">Price</a></th>
        <th style="width:20px;"><a href="#" class="pink">Category</a></th>

        <th style="width:50px;"><a href="#" class="pink">Edit</a></th>
        <th style="width:50px;"><a href="#" class="pink">Delete</a></th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $sql = "select * from tbl_house order by house_id";
    $rsd = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rsd)) {
        ?>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['house_id']; ?>"/></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['house_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['house_title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['house_price']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['category_id']; ?></td>
        <td><a  href="edit_view_house.php?id=<?php echo $row['house_id']; ?>"  ><img alt="" src="../images/adminicons/edit.png" width="22" height="22" border="0" /></a></td>
        <td><a  onClick="javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete...!');" href="delete_house.php?id=<?php echo $row['house_id']; ?>">
                <img alt="" src="../images/adminicons/delete.png" width="24" height="24" border="0" />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: this isn't what i'm looking for, i think what you posted is how to connect to a database in wamp for example and process data from it, what i'm looking for is just how to open for example a php file with a simple echo "hello world"; script into a div in another html file im working on.

Comment: @Crazyping12 I just want to show that how to put PHP code in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Using `(document).load();`

```
$(document).load(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#div").html('<object data="htmlfile.html" style="width:100%; height:100%;">');
    });
});
```

Comment: i'm already using that, what i showed is just a part of the code i used to load an html file into a div in my other html file.

Comment: So, why you post 2 answers?

Comment: @u_mulder load is also document's event. You can check over here "https://api.jquery.com/category/events/document-loading/"

Comment: @Crazyping12 My answer is helpful to you? Then please mark as acceptable and upvote, It's better to helps others also